# What is a linear functional on continuous functions on the real line not given by a measure?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

> What is a positive linear functional on continuous functions on the
>   real line not given by integration against a measure?

I know that the dual of $C_c(\mathbb R)$ is the set of Radon measures, and the dual of $C_0(\mathbb R)$ is the set of finite Radon measures, but I'm not sure how to construct the desired example. Presumably this is well-known.

This is question 1.9 from [this review list](http://web.math.princeton.edu/generals/real13.pdf).

Though the question is not too specific, I would like to consider both

- All continuous functions
- Bounded continuous functions

Can we construct examples in both cases?

Comment: Only continuous, or continuous and bounded?

Comment: @DanielFischer Sorry, I misunderstood your comment. Because I'm curious now, can we find examples for both cases?

Comment: For continuous and bounded, it is easy. A solution begins with "Let $\mathscr{U}$ be a free ultrafilter on $\mathbb{R}$". It's kind of cheating, however, since $C_b(X)\cong C(\beta X)$ (for completely regular $X$), so it's integration against a Dirac measure on $\beta\mathbb{R}$. Just one whose support lies outside $\mathbb{R}$. For continuous only, we have - assuming the standard topology on $C(\mathbb{R})$ - an embedding $$C(\mathbb{R})\hookrightarrow\prod_n C([-n,n]),$$ so every continuous linear functional is given by integration against a measure with compact support.

Comment: @DanielFischer Could you please explain your comment about the infinite product space a bit more? I'm not sure why it exists (what's the "standard topology"? sup norm?), or why it gives the characterization you claim. Also, what's a good reference for the material on Stone-Cech compactification used in the first part of your answer?

Comment: If you could assume differentiability, then $f\mapsto f'(0)$ is one example. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Not a **positive** linear functional.

Comment: @Potato The standard topology on $C(\mathbb{R})$ is the topology of locally uniform (or compact) convergence. Induced by the seminorms $\lVert f\rVert_K = \sup \{ \lvert f(x)\rvert : x \in K\}$ where $K$ runs through the compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. The intervals $[-n,n]$, where $n\in \mathbb{N}$ are sufficient to consider, since every compact set is contained in some such interval. Then you have an embedding $E \hookrightarrow \prod_{\alpha} E_{p_\alpha}$ for any Hausdorff locally convex space if $\{p_\alpha : \alpha \in \mathrm{A}\}$ is a family of seminorms inducing the topology.

Comment: A basis of neighbourhoods of $0$ is given by the intersection of balls of finitely many seminorms defining the topology. Here, we have an increasing sequence of seminorms, so a basis of neighbourhoods of $0$ is even given by the balls of a single seminorm. Thus any continuous linear functional is determined by the values on some interval $[-n,n]$ (of course $n$ depends on the functional), so is effectively an element of $C([-n,n])^\ast$, that is, a measure with support in $[-n,n]$. Regarding the Stone-Čech compactification, every good book on point set topology should go into that a bit.

Answer (score 2):

The spectrum of the $C^*$-algebra $C_b(\mathbb R)$ of bounded continuous functions on $\mathbb R$ corresponds to the Stone-Čech compactification $\beta \mathbb R$ of $\mathbb R$.
Any finite positive Borel measure on $\beta \mathbb R$ gives you a positive linear functional on $C_b(\mathbb R)$.  However, the points of $\beta \mathbb R \backslash \mathbb R$ live out in Axiom-of-Choice land: you won't find an "explicit" example.

Comment: Interesting! Thank you.